# Linkedin API / comment with media attachment

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to post comment on comment with media attachment(image) using linkedin API ,but i'm getting this error ,
{
"message": "java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:400]: com.linkedin.restli.client.RestLiResponseException: Response status 400, serviceErrorMessage: Comment media object must have either urn or image url, had neither",
"status": 400
}

i try using X-Restli-Protocol-Version 2.0.0 in heder but then im getting sytax exception , im using this endpoint for api , https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/urn:li:share:*******/comments

Answer (score 0):

Your LinkedIn-Version is too low, causing an upgrade to 202307 or higher